# Merge rows based on similar column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to summarize a table that has this information: Serial Number, StartDate, EndDate, StatusID and TimeInState, what I need is to merge rows that keep the same StatusId during a continuos time (EndDate of row is same as StartDate of the other), for example, for this case:

[image: Input]

I need to output something like this:

[image: Desired Output]

I can't come with a solution yet since I think I can't use `Group By`, I need to merge rows with specific SerialNumber when the StatusId doesn't change in a continuous time.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `group by`:

```
select serialnumber, min(begintime), max(endtime), statusid, sum(timeinms)
from t
group by serialnumber, statusid;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!, but that would  give me the total time that was in that StatuId?, what I need is one row for each period it was during  a statusId  (for example: from 1pm to 4pm it was status = 3 (1 row), then from 4pm to 5pm was statusId= 5 (another row), then from 5pm to 7pm it was statusId=3 again (another row) )

Comment: @JavierSantiagoCáceres . . . This corresponds to the data you have in your question -- hence, it answers the question that you *asked*.  If you have a different set of data, ask a *new* question and be clear about the rules you are using.